# I can't figure out my JavaScript function is not working

Tags: javascript

I have to create a game where the user has to guess a number, for that I call a JavaScript function on an external file which is activated when the button is clicked.

**My HTML**:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Devoir JavaScript</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Vous devez trouver un nombre compris entre 1 et 100 !</p>
    <form name="myForm" method="POST"></form>
      Nombre : <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" />
      <input type="button" onclick="return verif()" value="Jouer" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`
**My JavaScript**:

```
var numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var essai = 0;
function verif() {
  essai++;
  var choix = document.forms["myForm"]["choix"].value;
  if (choix == null || choix == "") {
    alert("Indiquer un nombre !");
    return false;
  }
  if (choix < numero) {
    alert = "Le nombre indiquer est trop petit !";
    return false;
  }
  if (choix > numero) {
    alert = "Le nombre indiquer est trop grand !";
    return false;
  }
  if (choix == numero) {
    alert = "Bravo vous avez trouver en " + essai + "essais !";
    return true;
  }
}
```

I have checked the name of my files and their extentions so as not to make a mistake.
I don't understand or I made a mistake.
PS: I am new to JavaScript.
I have been looking since yesterday so thank you for your help.

Comment: `JavaScript function is not working` is the function not called at all? Or is it called and does not what you expect (if so what does it do and what is the expected result)? Is there an error message in the developer console of the browser?

Comment: Yes there is an error message.
That says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at verif (script.js: 5)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html: 11) .

Comment: What do you expect that `document.forms["myForm"]["choix"]` should do?  You have no element for `choix` in your form. What should `"choix"` refer to in the form?

Comment: What I want to do with "document.forms["myForm"]["choix"]" is get the user's response.
In this case or should I put "choix"?

Comment: Yes, but to what element do you want to select in the form using `document.forms["myForm"]["choix"]` there is only one element and that has the name `nombre` (there is not element for `choix`). You are either missing an element in your form your you named it wrong in the HTML  or  js code.

Comment: I want to retrieve the user's response.

Comment: What is the `user's response`? is it the element **nombre**? If so why do you then look for the element **choix** which does not exists?

Comment: Yes the user's answer corresponds to "nombre".
I want to create a variable "choix" which retrieves the "nombre".

Comment: Ok but why do you then write `document.forms["myForm"]["choix"].value;` instead of `document.forms["myForm"]["nombre"].value;`?

Comment: Yes I had made a mistake that I modified but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and inside Console it says the value could not be read. I slightly changed your Javascript code and it worked.

```
//var choix = document.forms["myForm"]["choix"].value; code before

var choix = document.getElementsByName("nombre").value; //after changed
```

When using Javascript if your code is not running, you should press F12 and look at the Console to see what your code is failing.

This is the full code that I changed:

```js
var numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var essai = 0;
function verif() {
  essai++;
  var choix = document.getElementsByName("choix").value;
  document.write(choix);

  if (choix == null || choix == "") {
    alert("Indiquer un nombre !");
    return false;
  }
  if (choix < numero) {
    alert = "Le nombre indiquer est trop petit !";
    return false;
  }
  if (choix > numero) {
    alert = "Le nombre indiquer est trop grand !";
    return false;
  }
  if (choix == numero) {
    alert = "Bravo vous avez trouver en " + essai + "essais !";
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Devoir JavaScript</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Vous devez trouver un nombre compris entre 1 et 100 !</p>
    <form name="myForm" method="POST"></form>
      Nombre : <input type="number" name="choix" value=""/>
      <input type="button" onclick="return verif()" value="Jouer" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just modified with your code but still nothing happens.
I understood that it is blocking because of the fact that I do not have "" in my HTML and that I request it in JavaScript.
But now that I changed "onClick" to "onsubmit" and that I have but "submit" instead of "button" and that I put "var choice = document.getElementsByName (" number "). Value ; " instead of "var choice = document.forms [" myForm "] [" choice "]. value;".
I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: I also change "var choix" to "var nombre" and replace all "choix" with "nombre".

Comment: "var choix" to "var nombre" is not necessary, it has no effect on how your code works. However, you can change it if you want to give it a more recognizable variable name.

Comment: When you indicate a number it always asks "indiquer un nombre" which means indicate a number.

Answer (score -1):

Your error says that you are accessing the property `value` from `undefined`.
There is no "choix" in your HTML.

You can use indices to get your particular element value:

```
 var choix = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
```

Or keeping the same approach as yours, I can use the correct field "nombre" :

```
 var choix = document.forms["myForm"]["nombre"].value;
```

Comment: Changing from a solution that targets elements by name to one that uses indexes is probably not the best solution. What if another form is added to the page? What if another element is added to the form and the index changes?

Comment: I haven't seen the indexes in my lessons yet.

Comment: Yes. They are to get the first matching element. That can be problematic if you have multiple form elements. I have edited the answer so you can use names. But then again, i hope you are waiting for the the nombre field, because there is no choix field in the HTML. Use the second code snippet, it will helpyou.